# AdBlock users statistics

Tags: advertising, amazon, adblock

**Are there statistics of internet users that use AdBlock or other ad blocking plug-ins?**

Are there some statistical breakdown, for example, per country (I assume it must vary a lot)? I was unable to google the information I am looking for.

The reason I am asking is because I have just signed up for the "Amazon Partners" program and see that this affiliate program is listed on the AdBlock blacklist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a site that is selling some anti-adblock software: http://www.dsero.com/adblock-statistics-and-usage.html  but they do have graphs of ad-block usage.

They find that percent of ads blocked differs widely by type of site:

- Tech 16.98%
- Business 6.61%
- Lifestyle 4.09%

It also varies by country with Ukraine and Germany highest with around 20% of users having AdBlock installed.